# What tsc command does Visual Studio run when I save a Typescript file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a project in Visual Studio 2017 that uses Typescript.  I've set up the project so that when I save a *.ts file, Visual Studio compiles it (the default setting).  What command does Visual Studio actually run to compile the saved file?  I need to know because I want to run a similar command when I build my code on my build server.

Does Visual Studio just run `tsc <filename>.ts` for every saved file in my project?  Is there a command I can run that compiles all *.ts at once?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the exact command that is executed by MSBuild.

Change MSBuild to Detailed. Go to Tools->Options-> Project and Solution -> Build and Run. In the MSBuild project build **output** verbosity drop down select Detailed.

[image: Drop down]

After you rebuild your project search the output window for tsc.exe (Ctrl + F works fine) And you will find the exact command executed.[image]